# Injecting specific implementation of abstract Angular service into another Angular Service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

It is fairly simple to inject a specific child service into a component, but how to inject into another service?

Example:
Parent Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class ParentService {

  constructor() { }

  abstract testMe(): void;
}
```

Child Service

```js
import { ParentService } from "./parent.service";

export class ChildService implements ParentService {

  testMe(): void {
    console.log('child service');
  }
}
```

Component Injection

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildService } from './services/child.service';
import { ParentService } from './services/parent.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: ParentService, 
      useClass: ChildService 
    }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular_poc';

  constructor(private service: ParentService) {
    this.service.testMe();
  }

}
```

Child Service method is executed, so this works fine, but how to do the same in a new service, instead of component?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentService } from './parent.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class TestService {

  constructor(private service: ParentService) {  }

  run(){
    this.service.testMe();
  }
}
```

There's no providers in Injectable

Comment: The point of DI is that you _don't_ do that - your service isn't decoupled if it has to know which implementation of the interface it's going to get.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so can I do it on component level? can I specify inside of component where I inject TestService, which implementation of ParentService should the TestService use?

Comment: Why not just directly inject the child service? How is that any different from specifying the implementation in the providers array? It's not like you can configure a service's dependencies before it gets injected. Whereas a component you can configure before it gets instantiated.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton so what are my options if I want to inject different child classes based on some dynamic input during runtime?

Comment: I believe you can inject Angular's `Injector` service and use `injector.get()` to get any service at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up selecting which child service to inject in the component itself - component providers.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildService } from './services/child.service';
import { ParentService } from './services/parent.service';
import { TestService } from './services/test.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    TestService,
    { 
      provide: ParentService, 
      useClass: ChildService 
    }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular_poc';

  constructor(private service: TestService) {
    this.service.run();
  }

}
```