# Angular NullInjectorError under module-federation remoteEntry.js injecting an abstract service to another service across two Angular projects

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation, angular-standalone-components, angular-dependency-injection

I am getting a `NullInjectorError` error when I use an Angular component in a federated module (via `remoteEntry.js`), while it is working well in a standalone Angualar app.

It is (and has to be) a *standalone* angular component.

The service that I am injecting is declared via an abstract class (declared in the same Angular component library project), while the specific implementation is declared in a module in another project (to be able to have different implementations of the data access, depending on the environment, where the micro-frontend or the specific individual component is deployed).

I've built a repro sample. And here is the module/class/service design diagram:
[image]

But I am getting:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[FeatureComponent])[MassCommunicationService -> MassCommunicationService -> MassCommunicationService -> HelloService -> HelloService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HelloService!
```

Following repo shows the step-by-step configuration of the app shell and the federated module (both pretty standard) as per this article: [Dynamic Module Federation with Angular](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular/).

Least reproducible sample:
https://github.com/jan-dolejsi/angular-module-federation-sample/tree/service-to-service-injection

Note that the [main](https://github.com/jan-dolejsi/angular-module-federation-sample/) branch has the last working version (without the service-to-service injection) for comparison.

Answers provided elsewhere:

- [provide the specific implementation in the standalone component's provider list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71131425/1159548) is not applicable, because the service implementation depends on the environment where the component is used.
- [bootstrapping works differently for federated modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149091/1159548) is quite a helpful hint, however, again, the component should not know which specific implementation it should be using at runtime

Is this an impossible ask? A generic shared component with injectable service implementation provided by a module that is loaded via remoteEntry.js?

Help appreciated.